# DataTable - Getting error when putting select checkbox in first column

Tags: javascript, datatables

I know it has been addressed already, but I'm just not getting it to work. I'm using DataTable Editor with resposnive and serverside. I'm getting an error when I put the checkbox in the first column like:

js:

```
var table = $('#mytable').DataTable( {
    dom: "rt",
    ajax: {
        url: "/source.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: function (d) { 

        }
    },
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    select: {
        style:    'os',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },              
    columns: [
        {
            data: null,
            defaultContent: "",
            className: "select-checkbox",
            orderable: false, 
            targets:   0            
        },                                        
        { data: "logo" },
        { data: "name" },   
        { data: "product" }                                                
    ]                            
} );
```

That's the Error message:

DataTables warning: table id=mytable - Unknown field:  (index 0)

php:

```
Editor::inst( $db, 'table' )
    ->fields(
        Field::inst( 'logo' ),
        Field::inst( 'url' ),       
        Field::inst( 'name' ),
        Field::inst( 'product' )              
    )
```

... wenn putting in the last column it works:

```
    ...
    columns: [                                        
        { data: "logo" },
        { data: "name" },   
        { data: "product" },
        {
            data: null,
            defaultContent: "",
            className: "select-checkbox",
            orderable: false, 
            targets:   0            
        }                                                              
    ]   
    ...
```

How can I get the checkbox in the first column? (So column 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the answer from the author:

You have server-side processing enabled, and the default ordering is to order on the first column. When that happens, DataTables is telling the server to order on the client-side generated column and throws an error.

Use ``order: [[1, 'desc']]` to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

add this in code

```
 $("#table").DataTable({
            'columnDefs': [{
                    'targets': 0,
                    'bSortable': false,
                    'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
                            return '<input type="checkbox"> <label>Checkbox</label>';
                    }
            }]
 })
```

Comment: can you add a fiddle or working model of this issue?

Comment: can you pass checkbox html in defaultContent? I can only blindly say this until you post your fiddle, Thank you